# Switch from web-view to app view using Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

On mobile app, from the welcome screen when click user is redirect to next where I have a web-view display which is being called via API, now from that web view I wanted to come back to previous screen but its not sending back.

Please note that first screen is within app and second screen is web-view which is being displayed via API.

I have tried the following from web view:

```
<a href="javascript:history.back();">Back</a>
```

Comment: try to use javascript interface

Comment: @Pavya can you please provide more info? I already tried `window.close` and `history.back`

Comment: Are you using webView to load the web page?

Comment: @Nainal yes I am using webView to load web page

Comment: @SanjeevKumar I have added a answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a JavaScript function to finish the webView activity:-

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
```

Add Interface:-

```
public class WebAppInterface {
Context mContext;

/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

/** method to finish activity */
@JavascriptInterface
public void closeActivity() {
    MainActivity.this.finish();// MainActivity is your activity name which you want to close
}
}
```

And your HTML and JavaScript should contain something like this:-

```
<input type="button" value="Back" onClick="closeAndroidActivity()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function closeAndroidActivity() {
        Android.closeActivity();
    }
</script>
```

For more info refer  [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript)